# Nginx and Cakephp .conf file

Tags: cakephp, configuration, nginx

I want to run CakePHP 2.x under Nginx and everything works fine so far, except for the nginx.conf file. I currently don't know if I have to modify the nginx.conf file in the nginx root folder or if I have to create a new file in the cakephp webroot folder.

I'm also not sure about the content of the file, I have found a couple of examples online but they are different in slight details.

Is there maybe a good resource that explains in detail on how to set this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I got it working using this source: http://jedistirfry.co.uk/blog/2013-08/cakephp-config-for-nginx/

I edited the nginx.conf main file (inside the "conf" folder of nginx), specifically the "server" part that listens to port 80.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html#pretty-urls-on-nginx

If not try my config files.

cakephp2-rewrite-rules.conf

```
if (-f $request_filename) { 
    break; 
}     
if (!-f $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 last;
    break;
}
```

cake2app.conf

```
location / {
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    allow all;
    include cakephp2-rewrite-rules.conf;
}
include php-fastcgi.conf;
```

vhosts.conf

```
server {
  root          /foo/bar;
  listen        vhost:80;
  server_name   vhost;
  include       vhost/cake2app.conf;
}
```

Include the vhosts.conf in your nginx.conf in the http section.

```
include vhost/vhosts.conf;
```

Comment: Do I put this code in the main nginx.conf file or do I create a new nginx.conf file in the webroot folder?